# Picking first letter from user input

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, input

I would like to pick the first letter of a user input and use it for decision making in a loop.  A simple example:

```
play_again = input("Do you want to play again? (y/n)").lower()
```

The program should detect "Yes" as "Y" and "No" as "N".

Comment: So what is your problem exactly ? Extracting the first letter from the `play_again` variable?

Comment: You might want to have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/8881141

Answer (score 1):

To pick the first letter, simply add a `[0]` after your input. The `[0]` is string slicing - here it extracts only the first character of the string.

Also note, all inputs beginning with `'Y'` will be treated as the "yes" output, and all inputs beginning with `'N'` will be treated as the "no" output.

```
play_again = input("Do you want to play again? (y/n)").lower()
# Simply add [0]. But that does not work for empty strings.
if len(play_again) > 0) 
    play_again = play_again[0]
```

Please note that will not work if you provide an empty input - else a traceback will result stating `IndexError: string index out of range`. That is why there is an if-statement.

**Examples:**

```
Do you want to play again? (y/n)YES
y

Do you want to play again? (y/n)no
n

Do you want to play again? (y/n)OMG
o

Do you want to play again? (y/n)yakety yak
y

Do you want to play again? (y/n)
#Empty String
```

Answer (score 0):

```
play_again = input("Do you want to play again? (y/n)").lower()

if play_again in ['yes', 'no', 'y', 'n']:
    play_again = play_again[0]

    if play_again == 'y':
        # do something

    else:
        # do something else
```

Answer (score 0):

String indexing is similar to list indexing in Python. So you can index the 0th element directly:

```
play_again = input('Do you want to play again? (y/n)')[0].lower()
```

For example:

```
Do you want to play again? (y/n)Yes

print(play_again)

'y'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
play_again = input("Do you want to play again? (y/n)").lower()
first_letter=play_again[0]
#or
play_again = input("Do you want to play again? (y/n)").lower()[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is exactly what you are looking for:

```
play_again = input('Do you want to play again? (y/n)')[0].lower()

while(play_again=='y'):

    # Do something

    play_again = input('Do you want to play again? (y/n)')[0].lower()
```

**Explanation:**

`[0]` takes the first letter from the input string, `.lower()` will normalize the character to lower, Eg. **Y** or **y** to **y** and **N** or **n** to **n**.

The `while` loop trigger's for the first time if the user input's the string starting with **Y** or **y** and loops until repeated so. The break condition is input string not starting with **Y** or **y**.